# Honeywell C wire on a dual transformer system

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Currently I have dual transformer system
From heat >> RH & W1
From cool >> Y1, Rc, G

Honeywell provides a C wire adapter and also mentioned turning an unused wire into a C-wire. I do have an unused wire from the cool side. Mentioned in the manual is all about joining the adapter OR if there is an extra wire to furnace. My furnace wire up to the thermostat is only 2 wires.

Is it possible to use the cool transformer for the extra wire? Since I do have 2 unused wires

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the thermostat and at the air-handler please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel https://imgur.com/gallery/YV8IkLE

Comment: And @ThreePhaseEel https://imgur.com/gallery/OlZkpbH

Comment: It actually looks like the Blue is to the C... so can I just use that in the thermostat ?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I'd use the blue wire from the air handler as your C wire

From the pictures given, it does appear that the blue wire from the air handler is connected to C, so I'd just use that as your C wire.  Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Yup! Worked perfectly ! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @ATS -- we thank folks around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)